# How to run a python script remotly and caputre the output

Tags: python, shell, ssh, remote-access, spawn

I have a shell script in my server and I want it to run a python script in raspberry pi and get the result to my server's terminal.

To do it, I tried with `expect` package. This is my shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh pi@192.168.123.123

expect "password:"
send "pass\r"
interact


sudo python pi@192.168.123.123 TemparatureSensor/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 4
```

From this, I can access to the raspberry pi, but not executing the python script.

What am I missing here? How to get this into working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use subprocess module to capture output of a command

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it the other way around. Make a python script that executes a command (or you python script) and write the output to your terminal.

Here's an example of such python script, that in my case executes a command, adjusting the sound of my laptop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko
import sys

def sshConnect():
    HOST = "ip"
    USER = "user"
    KEYF = "/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa"
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(KEYF)
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print "[*] Connecting..."
    ssh.connect(hostname=HOST, username=USER, pkey=key)
    print "[+] Connected!"
    return ssh

def setVolume(ssh, volume):
    command = 'osascript -e "set Volume %s" ' % (volume)
    print "Executing %s" % (command)
    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read() #this prints the result in the terminal
    errors = stderr.read() 
    if errors:
        print errors
    ssh.close()
    print "[+] Disconnected"

def main(volume):
    setVolume(sshConnect(), volume)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```